# lastrowid() alternative or syntax without using execute in sqlite python?

Tags: python, sqlite

In sqlite3 in python, I'm trying to make a program where the new row in the table to be written will be inserted next, needs to be printed out. But I just read the [documentation here](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) that an INSERT should be used in execute() statement. Problem is that the program I'm making asks the user for his/her information and the primary key ID will be assigned for the member as his/her ID number must be displayed. So in other words, the execute("INSERT") statement must not be executed first as the ID Keys would be wrong for the assignment of the member.

I first thought that lastrowid can be run without using execute("INSERT") but I noticed that it always gave me the value "None". Then I read the documentation in sqlite3 in python and googled alternatives to solve this problem.

I've read through google somewhere that SELECT last_insert_rowid() can be used but would it be alright to ask what is the syntax of it in python? I've tried coding it like this

```
NextID = con.execute("select last_insert_rowid()")
```

But it just gave me an cursor object output ""

I've also been thinking of just making another table where there will always only be one value. It will get the value of lastrowid of the main table whenever there is a new input of data in the main table. The value it gets will then be inserted and overwritten in another table so that every time there is a new set of data needs to be input in the main table and the next row ID is needed, it will just access the table with that one value.

Or is there an alternative and easier way of doing this?

Any help is very much appreciated *bows deeply*

Comment: Insert a partial record, marked not enabled, now you have the data to display.  Update it with the full data and mark it enabled when you have the rest of the information.

Comment: @btilly - Would it be alright to ask how to make it marked as "not enabled" please? So you're saying is that when the full data will be added, it first removes the first data? I'm sorry, I'm not sure I quite understand ^^;;

Comment: I mean that you'd have a field in the row which in all of your queries you're filtering on to say, "Ignore this".  That starts off in the ignore state, and then you flip it when you finish.  If changing other queries is too hard, you can always have 2 tables.  You first insert in the one with a primary key id.  And then you copy finished data to the other, which doesn't try to create any primary key id.  That is wasteful, but may be easier to implement.

Comment: "select last_insert_rowid()" will only give you a result AFTER inserting data.

Answer (score 2):

You could *guess* the **next ID** if you would query your table **before asking the user** for his/her information with 
`SELECT MAX(ID) + 1 as NewID FROM DesiredTable`.

Before inserting the new data (including the new ID), start a transaction,
only rollback if the insert failes (because another process was faster with the same operation) and ask your user again. If eveything is OK just do a commit.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers and suggestions posted everyone but I ended up doing something like this:

```
#only to get the value of NextID to display
TempNick = "ThisIsADummyNickToBeDeleted"        
cur.execute("insert into Members (Nick) values (?)", (TempNick, ))
NextID = cur.lastrowid 
cur.execute("delete from Members where ID = ?",  (NextID, ))
```

So basically, in order to get the lastrowid, I ended up inserting a Dummy data then after getting the value of the lastrowid, the dummy data will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

lastrowid
This read-only attribute provides the rowid of the last modified row. It is only set if you issued an INSERT statement using the execute() method. For operations other than INSERT or when executemany() is called, lastrowid is set to None.

from  https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html